# Flutter - running two async in two widgets

Tags: flutter, list, dart, asynchronous, android-widget

I need to run the `async` method in one widget, but the widget is still waiting for the `async` method to end.

So I have this code:

```
class MainList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<TemplateData> list;

  TemplatesList({required this.list});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int index = (templates.length / 2).round();
    final listLeft =
    list.sublist(0, index);
    final listRight=
    list.sublist(index, templates.length);

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Flexible(child: _List(templateData: listLeft)),
            Flexible(child: _List(templateData: listRight)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _List extends StatefulWidget{
  final List<TemplateData> fileNames;

  const MemeList({required this.fileNames});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MemeListState();
}

class _ListState extends State<_List>{
  late List fileDownloaded;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fileDownloaded = widget.fileNames.map((e) => false).toList();
    downloadPreviews(widget.fileNames);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [for (String file in widget.fileNames) MyItem(name: file, is_downloaded:fileDownloaded[widget.fileNames.indexOf(file)],)],
    );
  }
  Future downloadFiles(List<TemplateData> fileNames) async {
    fileNames.forEach((file) async{
        await downloadFile(file);
        setState(() {
          fileDownloaded[widget.fileNames.indexOf(file)] = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In my app, I have two lists, one on the left and one on the right. When the app is built, files are downloaded for each list gradually. My problem with this is that the first list (on the left) is downloaded faster than the second. What I want is to download them simultaneously. I am a beginner in programming so I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `await` and replace it with `then()`.

```
Future downloadFiles(List<TemplateData> fileNames) async {
    for (final file in fileNames) {
      downloadFile(file).then(
        (_) => setState(() {
          fileDownloaded[widget.fileNames.indexOf(file)] = true;
        }),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think I explained it badly... I don’t need to wait for futures, I want to run them in both list simultaneously and set state every time some file is downloaded.